# How to call eval-last-sexp from a function

Tags: emacs

I would like to have a function that moves point to the end of the line (or marks the paragraph) and then evaluates. I got this working, but it does not have the nice error handling like the clean C-x C-e would do. Any ideas how to program this simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with straightforward definition?

```lisp
(defun my-eval-last-sexp (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (move-end-of-line 1)
  (eval-last-sexp arg))
```

Comment: What is arg doing here? Could you describe what is going on? This might very well be an answer.

Comment: The problem is that if it errors, you won't get a traceback/error, it will just give back `nil`

Comment: I tried `my-eval-last-exp` on `(+ bug 1)` and I got `*Backtrace*`. Could you please give me an example.

Comment: > arg doing here. I just want to pass an argument to `eval-last-sexp`.

Comment: Why `(setq a )` is error? It sets symbol `a` to `nil` and returns `nil`.

Comment: [Prefix Command Arguments](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info, and that was really unexpected! So indeed it worked all along!